# Javascript: strip tags ONLY IF tags found

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

**EDIT:** I have a function that wraps a string between tags. I want this function to apply only if the string does not contain any tags.

```
if string: "text" then "<b>text</b>";  
else if string "<b>text</b>" then "text";
```

I need a conditional statement that checks for given tags and strips the tags only if tags are found.

eg. `function stripTags(string, "span")`

1- search for given tags (span in this case)
2- if found, strip tags

Comment: Just strip tags. If there are none, nothing happens. No need to emphasize or check for "ONLY IF found".

Comment: @deceze: Im trying to wrap the string between tags only if It does not contains any. I dont want this-> <b><b>text</b></b>.

Comment: with simple tags like those you've given in the example, this is easily do-able as demonstrated in the answers below but in real-world html, if you don't control the input you will never be able to reliably identify tags - eg `<span class="blah" style="blah" id="blah">` or with params in a different order, etc... You also can't just assume anything between `<` and `>` is a tag eg the text could be `5 < 10 and 10 > 6`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function stripTags(string, tag) {
  var tagMatcher = new RegExp('</?' + tag + '>','g');
  return string.replace(tagMatcher, '');
}
```

to remove any tag from the string or

```
function toggleSurroundingTags(string, tag) {
  var tagMatcher = new RegExp('^<' + tag + '>(.*)</' + tag + '>$');
  var match = tagMatcher.exec(string);
  if (match) {
    return match[1];
  } else {
    return '<' + tag + '>' + string + '</' + tag + '>';
  }
}
```

To remove surrounding tags if they exist and add them if they don't exist:

```
toggleSurroundingTags('hello', 'b'); // returns '<b>hello</b>'
toggleSurroundingTags('<b>hello</b>', 'b'); // returns 'hello'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this code does not take any attributes in account.

Answer (score 3):

Check out:

- [PHPJS's strip_tags](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535)

**Source:**

```
function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Luke Godfrey
    // +      input by: Pul
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +      input by: Alex
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +      input by: Marc Palau
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Eric Nagel
    // +      input by: Bobby Drake
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Tomasz Wesolowski
    // +      input by: Evertjan Garretsen
    // +    revised by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl/)
    // *     example 1: strip_tags('<p>Kevin</p> <br /><b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>', '<i><b>');
    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin <b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>'
    // *     example 2: strip_tags('<p>Kevin <img src="someimage.png" onmouseover="someFunction()">van <i>Zonneveld</i></p>', '<p>');
    // *     returns 2: '<p>Kevin van Zonneveld</p>'
    // *     example 3: strip_tags("<a href='http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>", "<a>");
    // *     returns 3: '<a href='http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>'
    // *     example 4: strip_tags('1 < 5 5 > 1');
    // *     returns 4: '1 < 5 5 > 1'
    // *     example 5: strip_tags('1 <br/> 1');
    // *     returns 5: '1  1'
    // *     example 6: strip_tags('1 <br/> 1', '<br>');
    // *     returns 6: '1  1'
    // *     example 7: strip_tags('1 <br/> 1', '<br><br/>');
    // *     returns 7: '1 <br/> 1'

       allowed = (((allowed || "") + "")
          .toLowerCase()
          .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
          .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
       var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
           commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
       return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function($0, $1){
          return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
       });
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure if this is what I'm looking for. eg. I want to strip span tags ONLY if the string contains span tags.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a javascript answer. I'm not a jQuery guy... This makes use of the dom, so the browser's implementation may end up changing the case or dropping attributes it doesn't recognize...

```
function stripTags(string) {
    if (!arguments.callee._tempNode) {
        arguments.callee._tempNode = document.createElement('div');
    }
    var node = arguments.callee._tempNode;
    node.innerHTML = string;

    var i=arguments.length;
    while (--i) { // decrement first so the string var won't be processed
        var toRemove = node.getElementsByTagName(arguments[i]);
        while (toRemove.length) {
            toRemove[0].parentNode.removeChild(toRemove[0]);
        }        
    }
    return node.innerHTML;
}
```